# How multiple select to create a new row?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select

I have this code:

```
<select name="team[]" size="8" multiple="multiple">$team</select>
```

It lists for example players in that team, I want when user clicks on player it creates a new row where I can input basic info about player which I will add to database via php.

Comment: I'll be more specific:
that code I posted already works and it lists players, when player is clicked, a row appears where I can add info like score, ratio which will I add to databse...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, this is more about how you design your table and write your php than the HTML or the jQuery.

If you have a table like this:

```
table players:
player_id  int
first_name varchar(30)
last_name  varchar(60)
```

And another table like this:

```
table game_player_info:
id          int
player_id   int
goals       int
assists     int
penalties   int
notes       varchar(256)
```

Then you could pull the players out and populate the combo box.  The HTML you would generate would be something like this:

```
<select name="player">
    <option value="{put player_id here}">{put player name here}</option>
    <option value="{put player_id here}">{put player name here}</option>
    <option value="{put player_id here}">{put player name here}</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="goals"/>
<input type="text" name="assists"/>
<input type="text" name="penalties"/>
<textarea name="notes" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Then, when you submit, you could do a sql call with a query something like this (you would want to check for errors and sql injection, but this is a simple example):

```
insert into game_player_info (player_id, goals, assists, penalties, notes) 
  values ($_POST['player'], $_POST['goals'], $_POST['assists'], 
  $_POST['penalties'], $_POST['notes'])
```

Hope this helps.  If this does not answer your question, be sure to post more information for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

something like this I suppose and just call based on an id or something for the player.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    $("<input>", {

     id: "playerName",
     type: "text",
     value: "playerName"    

    }).appendTo('form');
});
```

});